# Server System Login Information

Tags: 16.04

Is there any way to get the system information at login (# of users logged in, IPs, processes, and also if any updates are available) without the news?

Comment: Do you mean the "news" that is in the file /etc/motd? Or something else?

Comment: What more do you want beyond what you get when you run _w_ in a terminal window? Ref.: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/w.procps.1.html Also see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/